# How can I find the most active time for a particular Facebook Group (best time to post)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I want to post on a Facebook group when *that* group is most active.

Is there anyway to get those sorts of stats for a particular Facebook Group?

Answer (score 1):

Pages have stats but groups do not. I suspect the best way is a manual review of when things are posted, and what gets the biggest likes, or the trial and error way of posting things at different times and analyzing which times give you the best results.

Answer (score 0):

[Buffer](https://buffer.com/) claims it can schedule your posts optimally. It supports pages and groups.

I also tried to look at [optimal posting time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213603/question-and-answer-activity-on-stackexchange-interactive-and-customized-editio) for Stack Exchange, but these results may be not extendable to other social services.